# PDO error: could not find driver

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Trying to connect with a database using PDO, I keep getting the error could "not find driver".  Looking online, I'm guessing this is a configuration error, but I don't know how to fix it.  Code:

```
try 
{
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dubook", "root", "password");
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    // more code here
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    echo "Connection to DB failed: " . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: Works fine for me, can't reproduce your error. Make sure your show us your **full** and **real** code here

Comment: Look in your php.ini file and uncomment all of the PDO drivers. Save the file and restart Apache. @Rizier123 you cannot reproduce because your system has the drivers installed.

Comment: Depends more on your PHP setup / distribution. Unless you let on some details about that, we can't help either.